# How to search for Outlook item subject by Excel range to return email address?

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have minimal experience coding.

I have code to read invoice numbers as range `c` in one workbook - `W1` -
 and return corresponding values relating to invoice fees and due dates from another workbook - `W2`. The code runs as intended.

I would like to use the same range `c` to search sent items in Outlook for subject lines containing the `c` values, and return to `W1` the recipient's email address and name.

For example, an invoice number could be displayed "201x/xxxx", the subject of the email would read "Invoice from ABC Ltd - 201x/xxxx", the code would return to `W1` the required data.

I have attempted to apply the `Like` function.

Below is the code as it stands;

```
Sub UpdateDunningLog()

'defining source and target workbooks
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

'c will be the matched value (invoice number)
Dim c As Range, FR As Long

'defining debtor log
Dim strfilename As String: strfilename = "xyz.xlsx"

Dim DL As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'sets active worksheet to Dunning Log
Set w2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'sets debtor log to open (in background)
Set DL = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strfilename, UpdateLinks:=3)      
Set w1 = DL.Worksheets("Data")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False  

'c is invoice number, macro begins reading at A4
' and continues until there are no remaining rows
For Each c In w1.Range("A4", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))      

    FR = 0

    On Error Resume Next
    'matches invoice nummbers from debtor log to Dunning Log
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("E"), 0)                    
    On Error GoTo 0

    'if there is a match, client name is extracted
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("D" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 3)

    'if there is a match, invoice value is extracted
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("G" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 15)

    'if there is a match, overdue days are extracted
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("H" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 41)

Next c         'loops through each invoice number

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'closes debtor log, ensuring it stays in the background throughout the process
DL.Close savechanges:=False   

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olNS As Namespace
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String
Dim olMail As Object

MailBoxName = "xyz@xyz.xyz"
Pst_Folder_Name = "Sent Items"

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)                            

i = 1
For Each olMail In Folder.Items

    If olMail.Subject Like "*c*" Then _
      w2.Range("A" & FR).Value = Folder.Items.Item(i).RecipientName
    If olMail.Subject Like "*c*" Then _
      w2.Range("B" & FR).Value = Folder.Items.Item(i).RecipientEmailAddress
    On Error GoTo 0
    i = i + 1

Next olMail

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This line `olMail.Subject Like "*c*"` is looking for emails that contain the letter **C** in the subject line.  To extract the value from range object `c`:

```
Dim SearchFor As String
SearchFor = "*" & c.Value & "*"

If olMail.Subject Like SearchFor Then
```

In the example, I've used [string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) to build the search pattern.  I've used a separate variable, although you don't have to.

You mentioned that your code is growing in size and becoming muddled.  This is a common problem.  One way of staying on top is to break your code into a number of smaller units.  Rough example:

```
' Code execution starts here.
Sub EntryPoint
    Dim iNums As Range
    Dim iNum As Range
    Dim CurrentSubject As String

    Set iNums = GetInvoiceNumbers()   
    For Each iNum In iNums
        CurrentSubject = GetEmailSubject(iNum)
    Next      
End Sub

' Returns a list of invoice numbers.
Function GetInvoiceNumbers() As Range

    ' ...Code here...
End Function

' Checks Outlet mailbox.
Function GetEmailSubject(ByVal InvoiceNumber As String) As String

    ' ...Code here...
End Function
```

Make sure each sub/function has one, and only job.  Give it a meaningful name and soon you'll be able to speed read your code while looking for the right place to make the next change.

**Edit**

Ok so I missed a few important details in the OPs code.  This is my reworked answer:

I've added a new function that extracts email details for the current invoice.

```
' Checks the xyz mailbox for any items with the supplied
' invoice number in the sent items folder.
'
'   InvoiceNumber               Invoice to search for.
'   RecipientNameCell           Cell to write name to.
'   RecipientEmailAddressCell   Cell to write email address to.
Sub ExtractEmailDetails(ByVal InvoiceNumber As String, ByRef RecipientNameCell As Range, ByRef RecipientEmailAddressCell As Range)

    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim SentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OlMail As Object

    Set OlApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set SentFolder = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

    For Each OlMail In SentFolder.Items

        ' Ignore notes and other items that might be stored in the folder.
        If TypeName(OlMail) = "MailItem" Then
            If OlMail.Subject Like "*" & InvoiceNumber & "*" Then

                RecipientNameCell.Value = OlMail.Recipients.Item(1).Name
                RecipientEmailAddressCell = OlMail.Recipients.Item(1).Address
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can call this from the existing loop in your code:

```
For Each c In w1.Range("A4", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))      'c is invoice number, macro begins reading at A4 and continues until there are no remaining rows
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("E"), 0)                       'matches invoice nummbers from debtor log to Dunning Log
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("D" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 3)           'if there is a match, client name is extracted
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("G" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 15)          'if there is a match, invoice value is extracted
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("H" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 41)          'if there is a match, overdue days are extracted

    ' NEW LINE BELOW.
    ExtractEmailDetails c.Value, w2.Range("A" & FR).Value, w2.Range("B" & FR).Value
Next c         'loops through each invoice number
```

`ExtractEmailDetails` is executed once for each matched invoice number.  It checks the entire sent box.  At the moment if it finds more than 1 match only the last name/address found is written to Excel.  To change this you'd need to allow for more rows or columns.  Also, an email could have multiple recipients.  Here details are extracted for the first.  You could extract them all, either into a long field or additional rows/columns.

Without the spreadsheets, I couldn't fully test the code.  The new function may require a little tweaking ;).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately the line 
`SearchFor = "*" & c.Value & "*"` returns the error: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot.  I skimmed your code and missed a few important details.  Hold on I'll rework my answer...